# Can't get the right values with the pulse sensor and the LM35 temperature sensor . Reading 2 anolog sesnors

Tags: arduino-uno, lm35

I am trying to combine the two sensors (pulse sensor using [this library](https://github.com/WorldFamousElectronics/PulseSensorPlayground) and LM35 temp)(on a Arduino UNO board),but there is a problem with them when is a noise at the pulse sensor .The values are fluctuates especially the LM35 it goes from 31 degrees (normal value ) to 25-50 and even the pulse one changes .

Here are the [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG9ec.jpg) .

The code is this(I got the code form the  Getting_BPM_to_Monitor sketch ) :

```
#define USE_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTS true    // Set-up low-level interrupts for most acurate BPM math.
#include <PulseSensorPlayground.h>     // Includes the PulseSensorPlayground Library. 

const int sensor = A5; // Assigning analog pin A5 to variable ‘sensor’
float tempc; //variable to store temperature in degree Celsius
float vout; //temporary variable to hold sensor reading
//  Variables
const int PulseWire = 0;       // PulseSensor PURPLE WIRE connected to ANALOG PIN 0
const int LED13 = 13;          // The on-board Arduino LED, close to PIN 13.
int Threshold = 550;           // Determine which Signal to "count as a beat" and which to ignore.
// Use the "Gettting Started Project" to fine-tune Threshold Value beyond default setting.
// Otherwise leave the default "550" value.

PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;  // Creates an instance of the PulseSensorPlayground object called "pulseSensor"
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);          // For Serial Monitor
  // Configure the PulseSensor object, by assigning our variables to it.
  pulseSensor.analogInput(PulseWire);
  pulseSensor.blinkOnPulse(LED13);       //auto-magically blink Arduino's LED with heartbeat.
  pulseSensor.setThreshold(Threshold);
  // Double-check the "pulseSensor" object was created and "began" seeing a signal.
  if (pulseSensor.begin()) {
    Serial.println("We created a pulseSensor Object !");  //This prints one time at Arduino power-up,  or on Arduino reset.
  }
}

void loop() {
  int temp = analogTemp();
  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.println("Temp");

  if (pulseSensor.sawStartOfBeat()) {            // Constantly test to see if "a beat happened".
    // Serial.println("♥  A HeartBeat Happened ! "); // If test is "true", print a message "a heartbeat happened".
    int myBPM = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();  // Calls function on our pulseSensor object that returns BPM as an "int".
    // "myBPM" hold this BPM value now.
    Serial.print("BPM: ");                        // Print phrase "BPM: "
    Serial.print(myBPM);                        // Print the value inside of myBPM.
    Serial.println(" A HeartBeat Happened ! ");
  }
  delay(20);                    // considered best practice in a simple sketch.
}
float analogTemp() {
  vout = analogRead(sensor);
  vout = (vout * 500) / 1023;
  return vout; // Storing value in Degree Celsius

}
```

Comment: Do all devices share a common ground?

Comment: This may be a hardware problem (eg wrong/no capacitors etc). Can you please post your schematic.

Comment: Yes they share the same ground .Here is the [scheme](https://imgur.com/a/IBjuN2Z)

Comment: I used this [pulse sensor](https://nevonexpress.com/Heartbeat-Sensor-Module.php)